# how to retrieve the return value of a function in an external javascript on a webpag, better with python + selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I am building a personal quantum trading website to achieve a higher return rate. Before this I need some history financial data (MACD, KSJ, RSI and etc.) from a well-known website:

http://quote.eastmoney.com/bk/90.BK0473.html

As of this moment, I manage to locate the expected data, which is the return value of a function inside an external javascript of the webpage. But I fail to get the data in a automated way. I can just console.log() it with the browser's developer tool, which is far from enough.

Problem is: how can I retrieve the data in a script-like way, saving the data somewhere eles, and better with the Python + Selenium frame? I want to use it in Python or 'download' it to a local file possibly, and sort this data to my own database at last.

It's also welcome if it's not achieved with Python + Selenium, I need it badly in every possible way.

Here is the external javascript in that page:

view-source:http://quote.eastmoney.com/bk/90.BK0473.html

```html
<script src="//emcharts.eastmoney.com/ec/3.17.0/emcharts.min.js"></script>
```

The absolute path of the javascript is:

http://emcharts.eastmoney.com/ec/3.17.0/emcharts.min.js

The expected MACD, KDJ, RSI data lives here:

```js
t.exports = function (t, e) {
        for (var i = function (t) {
                null == t || t.Count;
                for (var e, i, n, a, o, r, s, l, h, d, c, p, g, u, f, A, m, C, v, y, x, I, b, w, k, M, T, R, D, E = [], S = t.length, _ = 0; _ < S; _++) {
                    var O = t[_].split(","),
                        j = {
                            Average5: 0,
                            Average10: 0,
                            Average20: 0,
                            Average30: 0,
                            Average3: 0,
                            Average6: 0,
                            Average12: 0,
                            Average24: 0,
                            Average50: 0,
                            Average60: 0,
                            ASI: 0,
                            BIAS_A: 0,
                            BIAS_B: 0,
                            BIAS_C: 0,
                            BOLL: 0,
                            BOLL_UPPER: 0,
                            BOLL_LOWER: 0,
                            CCI_TYP: 0,
                            CCI: 0,
                            CR_MID: 0,
                            CR_AX: 0,
                            CR_BX: 0,
                            CR: 0,
                            CR_A: 0,
                            CR_B: 0,
                            CR_C: 0,
                            DMI_TR: 0,
                            DMI_DMP: 0,
                            DMI_DMM: 0,
                            DMI_EXPMEMA_TR: 0,
                            DMI_EXPMEMA_DMP: 0,
                            DMI_EXPMEMA_DMM: 0,
                            DMI_PDI: 0,
                            DMI_MDI: 0,
                            DMI_MPDI: 0,
                            DMI_ADX: 0,
                            DMI_ADXR: 0,
                            KDJ_RSV: 0,
                            KDJ_K: 0,
                            KDJ_D: 0,
                            KDJ_J: 0,
                            MACD_AX: 0,
                            MACD_BX: 0,
                            MACD_DIF: 0,
                            MACD_DEA: 0,
                            MACD: 0,
                            OBV: 0,
                            OBV_MA: 0,
                            ROC: 0,
                            ROC_MA: 0,
                            RSI_UP_A: 0,
                            RSI_DN_A: 0,
                            RSI_UP_B: 0,
                            RSI_DN_B: 0,
                            RSI_UP_C: 0,
                            RSI_DN_C: 0,
                            RSI_A: 0,
                            RSI_B: 0,
                            RSI_C: 0,
                            SAR: 0,
                            SAR_RED: 0,
                            VR: 0,
                            VR_MA: 0,
                            WR_A: 0,
                            WR_B: 0,
                            BBI: 0,
                            Zero: 0,
                            volume5: 0,
                            volume10: 0,
                            time: 0,
                            open: 0,
                            close: 0,
                            high: 0,
                            low: 0,
                            volume: 0
                        };
                    j.time = O[0],
                        j.open = parseFloat(O[1]),
                        j.close = parseFloat(O[2]),
                        j.high = parseFloat(O[3]),
                        j.low = parseFloat(O[4]),
                        j.volume = Number(O[5]),
                        E.push(j)
                }
                for (var B, L = !0, N = 0, G = 0, _ = 0; _ < S; _++) {
                    if (4 <= _) {
                        for (var W = i = e = 0; W < 5; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].close,
                            i += E[_ - W].volume;
                        E[_].Average5 = e / 5,
                            E[_].volume5 = i / 5
                    }
                    if (9 <= _) {
                        for (W = i = e = 0; W < 10; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].close,
                            i += E[_ - W].volume;
                        E[_].Average10 = e / 10,
                            E[_].volume10 = i / 10
                    }
                    if (19 <= _) {
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 20; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].close;
                        E[_].Average20 = e / 20
                    }
                    if (29 <= _) {
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 30; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].close;
                        E[_].Average30 = e / 30
                    }
                    if (2 <= _) {
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 3; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].close;
                        E[_].Average3 = e / 3
                    }
                    if (5 <= _) {
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 6; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].close;
                        E[_].Average6 = e / 6
                    }
                    if (11 <= _) {
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 12; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].close;
                        E[_].Average12 = e / 12
                    }
                    if (23 <= _) {
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 24; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].close;
                        E[_].Average24 = e / 24
                    }
                    if (49 <= _) {
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 50; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].close;
                        E[_].Average50 = e / 50
                    }
                    if (59 <= _) {
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 60; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].close;
                        E[_].Average60 = e / 60
                    }
                    if (1 <= _ && (n = E[_ - 1].close,
                            a = Math.abs(E[_].high - n),
                            o = Math.abs(E[_].low - n),
                            r = Math.abs(E[_].high - E[_ - 1].low),
                            s = Math.abs(n - E[_ - 1].open),
                            l = o < a && r < a ? a + o / 2 + s / 4 : r < o && a < o ? o + a / 2 + s / 4 : r + s / 4,
                            h = E[_].close + (E[_].close - E[_].open) / 2 - E[_ - 1].open,
                            0 != l && (E[_].ASI = E[_ - 1].ASI + 16 * h / l * Math.max(a, o))),
                        5 <= _) {
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 6; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].close;
                        0 != e && (E[_].BIAS_A = 100 * (E[_].close / (e / 6) - 1))
                    }
                    if (11 <= _) {
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 12; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].close;
                        0 != e && (E[_].BIAS_B = 100 * (E[_].close / (e / 12) - 1))
                    }
                    if (23 <= _) {
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 24; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].close;
                        0 != e && (E[_].BIAS_C = 100 * (E[_].close / (e / 24) - 1))
                    }
                    if (19 <= _) {
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 20; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].close;
                        E[_].BOLL = e / 20;
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 20; W++)
                            e += (E[_ - W].close - E[_].BOLL) * (E[_ - W].close - E[_].BOLL);
                        d = parseFloat(Math.sqrt(e / 20)),
                            E[_].BOLL_UPPER = E[_].BOLL + 2 * d,
                            E[_].BOLL_LOWER = E[_].BOLL - 2 * d
                    }
                    if (E[_].CCI_TYP = (E[_].high + E[_].low + E[_].close) / 3,
                        13 <= _) {
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 14; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].close;
                        0;
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 14; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].CCI_TYP;
                        c = e / 14;
                        for (W = e = 0; W < 14; W++)
                            e += Math.abs(E[_ - W].CCI_TYP - c);
                        0 != e && (E[_].CCI = (E[_].CCI_TYP - c) / (e / 14 * .015))
                    }
                    if (E[_].CR_MID = (E[_].high + E[_].low) / 2,
                        0 == _)
                        E[_].CR = 100,
                        E[_].CR_AX = Math.max(E[_].high - E[_].CR_MID, 0),
                        E[_].CR_BX = Math.max(E[_].CR_MID - E[_].low, 0);
                    else {
                        E[_].CR_AX = Math.max(E[_].high - E[_ - 1].CR_MID, 0),
                            E[_].CR_BX = Math.max(E[_ - 1].CR_MID - E[_].low, 0);
                        for (W = p = g = 0; W < 26 && W < _ + 1; W++)
                            p += E[_ - W].CR_AX,
                            g += E[_ - W].CR_BX;
                        if (0 != g && (E[_].CR = p / g * 100),
                            9 <= _) {
                            for (W = e = 0; W < 10; W++)
                                e += E[_ - W].CR;
                            _ + 5 < E.Length && (E[_ + 5].CR_A = e / 10)
                        }
                        if (19 <= _) {
                            for (W = e = 0; W < 20; W++)
                                e += E[_ - W].CR;
                            _ + 9 < E.Length && (E[_ + 9].CR_B = e / 20)
                        }
                        if (39 <= _) {
                            for (W = e = 0; W < 40; W++)
                                e += E[_ - W].CR;
                            _ + 17 < E.Length && (E[_ + 17].CR_C = e / 40)
                        }
                    }
                    if (f = 0 == _ ? (E[_].DMI_TR = Math.max(Math.max(E[_].high - E[_].low, Math.abs(E[_].high - E[_].close)), Math.abs(E[_].close - E[_].low)),
                            u = 0) : (E[_].DMI_TR = Math.max(Math.max(E[_].high - E[_].low, Math.abs(E[_].high - E[_ - 1].close)), Math.abs(E[_ - 1].close - E[_].low)),
                            u = E[_].high - E[_ - 1].high,
                            E[_ - 1].low - E[_].low),
                        E[_].DMI_DMP = 0 < u && f < u ? u : 0,
                        E[_].DMI_DMM = 0 < f && u < f ? f : 0,
                        13 <= _) {
                        if (13 == _) {
                            for (W = A = m = C = 0; W < 14; W++)
                                A += E[_ - W].DMI_TR,
                                m += E[_ - W].DMI_DMP,
                                C += E[_ - W].DMI_DMM;
                            E[_].DMI_EXPMEMA_TR = A / 14,
                                E[_].DMI_EXPMEMA_DMP = m / 14,
                                E[_].DMI_EXPMEMA_DMM = C / 14
                        } else
                            E[_].DMI_EXPMEMA_TR = (2 * E[_].DMI_TR + 13 * E[_ - 1].DMI_EXPMEMA_TR) / 15,
                            E[_].DMI_EXPMEMA_DMP = (2 * E[_].DMI_DMP + 13 * E[_ - 1].DMI_EXPMEMA_DMP) / 15,
                            E[_].DMI_EXPMEMA_DMM = (2 * E[_].DMI_DMM + 13 * E[_ - 1].DMI_EXPMEMA_DMM) / 15;
                        0 != E[_].DMI_EXPMEMA_TR && (E[_].DMI_PDI = 100 * E[_].DMI_EXPMEMA_DMP / E[_].DMI_EXPMEMA_TR,
                            E[_].DMI_MDI = 100 * E[_].DMI_EXPMEMA_DMM / E[_].DMI_EXPMEMA_TR,
                            E[_].DMI_PDI + E[_].DMI_MDI != 0 && (E[_].DMI_MPDI = Math.abs(E[_].DMI_MDI - E[_].DMI_PDI) / (E[_].DMI_MDI + E[_].DMI_PDI) * 100))
                    }
                    if (18 <= _)
                        if (18 == _) {
                            for (W = v = 0; W < 6; W++)
                                v += E[_ - W].DMI_MPDI;
                            E[_].DMI_ADX = v / 6
                        } else
                            E[_].DMI_ADX = (2 * E[_].DMI_MPDI + 5 * E[_ - 1].DMI_ADX) / 7;
                    if (23 <= _)
                        if (23 == _) {
                            for (W = y = 0; W < 6; W++)
                                y += E[_ - W].DMI_ADX;
                            E[_].DMI_ADXR = y / 6
                        } else
                            E[_].DMI_ADXR = (2 * E[_].DMI_ADX + 5 * E[_ - 1].DMI_ADXR) / 7;
                    x = E[_].low,
                        I = E[_].high;
                    for (W = 0; W < 9 && W < _ + 1; W++)
                        I < E[_ - W].high && (I = E[_ - W].high),
                        x > E[_ - W].low && (x = E[_ - W].low);
                    if (I != x && (E[_].KDJ_RSV = (E[_].close - x) / (I - x) * 100),
                        0 == _ ? (E[_].KDJ_K = E[_].KDJ_RSV,
                            E[_].KDJ_D = E[_].KDJ_RSV,
                            E[_].KDJ_J = E[_].KDJ_RSV) : (E[_].KDJ_K = E[_].KDJ_RSV / 3 + 2 * E[_ - 1].KDJ_K / 3,
                            E[_].KDJ_D = E[_].KDJ_K / 3 + 2 * E[_ - 1].KDJ_D / 3,
                            E[_].KDJ_J = 3 * E[_].KDJ_K - 2 * E[_].KDJ_D),
                        0 == _ ? (E[_].MACD_AX = E[_].close,
                            E[_].MACD_BX = E[_].close,
                            E[_].MACD_DIF = 0,
                            E[_].MACD_DEA = 0) : (E[_].MACD_AX = (2 * E[_].close + 11 * E[_ - 1].MACD_AX) / 13,
                            E[_].MACD_BX = (2 * E[_].close + 25 * E[_ - 1].MACD_BX) / 27,
                            E[_].MACD_DIF = E[_].MACD_AX - E[_].MACD_BX,
                            E[_].MACD_DEA = (2 * E[_].MACD_DIF + 8 * E[_ - 1].MACD_DEA) / 10),
                        0 < _ && (E[_].close > E[_ - 1].close ? E[_].OBV = E[_ - 1].OBV + E[_].volume : E[_].close < E[_ - 1].close ? E[_].OBV = E[_ - 1].OBV - E[_].volume : E[_].OBV = E[_ - 1].OBV,
                            29 <= _)) {
                        for (var W = b = 0; W < 30; W++)
                            b += E[_ - W].OBV;
                        E[_].OBV_MA = b / 30
                    }
                    if (w = Math.min(11, _),
                        0 != E[_ - w].close && (E[_].ROC = 100 * (E[_].close / E[_ - w].close - 1)),
                        5 <= _) {
                        for (var W = e = 0; W < 6; W++)
                            e += E[_ - W].ROC;
                        E[_].ROC_MA = e / 6
                    }
                    if (0 < _ && (k = Math.max(E[_].close - E[_ - 1].close, 0),
                            M = Math.abs(E[_].close - E[_ - 1].close),
                            1 == _ ? (E[_].RSI_UP_A = k,
                                E[_].RSI_DN_A = M,
                                E[_].RSI_UP_B = k,
                                E[_].RSI_DN_B = M,
                                E[_].RSI_UP_C = k,
                                E[_].RSI_DN_C = M) : (E[_].RSI_UP_A = k + 5 * E[_ - 1].RSI_UP_A / 6,
                                E[_].RSI_DN_A = M + 5 * E[_ - 1].RSI_DN_A / 6,
                                E[_].RSI_UP_B = k + 11 * E[_ - 1].RSI_UP_B / 12,
                                E[_].RSI_DN_B = M + 11 * E[_ - 1].RSI_DN_B / 12,
                                E[_].RSI_UP_C = k + 23 * E[_ - 1].RSI_UP_C / 24,
                                E[_].RSI_DN_C = M + 23 * E[_ - 1].RSI_DN_C / 24)),
                        3 == _) {
                        if (L) {
                            G = E[_].high;
                            for (W = 0; W < 4; W++)
                                G < E[_ - W].high && (G = E[_ - W].high);
                            N = E[_].low;
                            for (W = 0; W < 4; W++)
                                N > E[_ - W].low && (N = E[_ - W].low);
                            E[_].SAR = N,
                                E[_].SAR_RED = !0,
                                L = !.02
                        }
                    } else
                        3 < _ && ! function t(e, i) {
                            if (et) {
                                if (tt) {
                                    at = i[e].high;
                                    for (var n = 0; n < 2; n++)
                                        at < i[e - n].high && (at = i[e - n].high);
                                    nt = i[e].low;
                                    for (var n = 0; n < 2; n++)
                                        nt > i[e - n].low && (nt = i[e - n].low);
                                    i[e].SAR = nt,
                                        i[e].SAR_RED = !0,
                                        it = .02
                                } else {
                                    at = i[e].high;
                                    for (var n = 0; n < 2; n++)
                                        at < i[e - n].high && (at = i[e - n].high);
                                    nt = i[e].low;
                                    for (var n = 0; n < 2; n++)
                                        nt > i[e - n].low && (nt = i[e - n].low);
                                    i[e].SAR = at,
                                        i[e].SAR_RED = !1,
                                        it = .02
                                }
                                et = !1
                            } else
                                tt ? (i[e].SAR = i[e - 1].SAR + it * (at - i[e - 1].SAR),
                                    i[e].SAR_RED = !0,
                                    i[e].high > at && (at = i[e].high,
                                        it = Math.min(it + .02, .2)),
                                    i[e].SAR > i[e].close && (et = !(tt = !1),
                                        t(e, i))) : (i[e].SAR = i[e - 1].SAR + it * (nt - i[e - 1].SAR),
                                    i[e].SAR_RED = !1,
                                    i[e].low < nt && (nt = i[e].low,
                                        it = Math.min(it + .02, .2)),
                                    i[e].SAR < i[e].close && (et = tt = !0,
                                        t(e, i)))
                        }(_, E);
                    for (W = T = R = D = 0; W < 26 && W < _ + 1; W++)
                        W + 1 <= _ ? E[_ - W].close > E[_ - W - 1].close ? T += E[_ - W].volume : E[_ - W].close < E[_ - W - 1].close ? R += E[_ - W].volume : D += E[_ - W].volume : (T += E[_ - W].volume / 3,
                            R += E[_ - W].volume / 3,
                            D += E[_ - W].volume / 3);
                    if (2 * R + D != 0 && (E[_].VR = 100 * (2 * T + D) / (2 * R + D)),
                        5 <= _) {
                        for (W = B = 0; W < 6; W++)
                            B += E[_ - W].VR;
                        E[_].VR_MA = B / 6
                    }
                    x = E[_].low,
                        I = E[_].high;
                    for (W = 0; W < 10 && W < _ + 1; W++)
                        I < E[_ - W].high && (I = E[_ - W].high),
                        x > E[_ - W].low && (x = E[_ - W].low);
                    I != x && (E[_].WR_A = 100 * (I - E[_].close) / (I - x)),
                        x = E[_].low,
                        I = E[_].high;
                    for (W = 0; W < 6 && W < _ + 1; W++)
                        I < E[_ - W].high && (I = E[_ - W].high),
                        x > E[_ - W].low && (x = E[_ - W].low);
                    I != x && (E[_].WR_B = 100 * (I - E[_].close) / (I - x)),
                        23 <= _ && (E[_].BBI = (E[_].Average3 + E[_].Average6 + E[_].Average12 + E[_].Average24) / 4)
                }
                return E
            }(e), n = [], a = i.length, o = 0; o < a; o++) {
            var r, s, l, h = i[o],
                d = {};
            switch (t) {
                case "VAVERAGE":
                    var c = void 0 === h.volume5 ? "-" : +h.volume5.toFixed(3),
                        p = void 0 === h.volume10 ? "-" : +h.volume10.toFixed(3);
                    d = [h.time, c, p],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "CMA":
                    var g = void 0 === h.Average5 ? "-" : +h.Average5.toFixed(3),
                        u = void 0 === h.Average10 ? "-" : +h.Average10.toFixed(3),
                        f = void 0 === h.Average20 ? "-" : +h.Average20.toFixed(3),
                        A = void 0 === h.Average30 ? "-" : +h.Average30.toFixed(3),
                        m = void 0 === h.Average60 ? "-" : +h.Average60.toFixed(3);
                    d = [h.time, g, u, f, m],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "MA":
                    var g = void 0 === h.Average5 ? "-" : h.Average5.toFixed(3),
                        u = void 0 === h.Average10 ? "-" : h.Average10.toFixed(3),
                        f = void 0 === h.Average20 ? "-" : h.Average20.toFixed(3),
                        A = void 0 === h.Average30 ? "-" : h.Average30.toFixed(3),
                        C = void 0 === h.Average3 ? "-" : h.Average3.toFixed(3),
                        v = void 0 === h.Average6 ? "-" : h.Average6.toFixed(3),
                        y = void 0 === h.Average12 ? "-" : h.Average12.toFixed(3),
                        x = void 0 === h.Average24 ? "-" : h.Average24.toFixed(3),
                        I = void 0 === h.Average50 ? "-" : h.Average50.toFixed(3),
                        m = void 0 === h.Average60 ? "-" : h.Average60.toFixed(3);
                    d[h.time] = [g, u, f, A, C, v, y, x, I, m],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "ASI":
                    var b = void 0 === h.ASI ? "-" : h.ASI.toFixed(3);
                    d[h.time] = [b],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "EXPMA":
                    y = void 0 === h.Average12 ? "-" : h.Average12.toFixed(3),
                        I = void 0 === h.Average50 ? "-" : h.Average50.toFixed(3);
                    d = [h.time, y, I],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "SAR":
                    var w = void 0 === h.SAR ? "-" : h.SAR.toFixed(3);
                    d = [h.time, w],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "BBI":
                    var k = void 0 === h.BBI ? "-" : h.BBI.toFixed(3);
                    d = [h.time, k],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "RSI":
                    d = 4 < o ? (r = 0 == h.RSI_DN_A ? "-" : +(h.RSI_UP_A / h.RSI_DN_A * 100).toFixed(3),
                            s = 0 == h.RSI_DN_B ? "-" : +(h.RSI_UP_B / h.RSI_DN_B * 100).toFixed(3),
                            l = "0" == h.RSI_DN_C ? "-" : +(h.RSI_UP_C / h.RSI_DN_C * 100).toFixed(3),
                            [h.time, r, s, l]) : ["-", "-", "-", "-"],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "KDJ":
                    var M = void 0 === h.KDJ_K ? "-" : +h.KDJ_K.toFixed(3),
                        T = void 0 === h.KDJ_D ? "-" : +h.KDJ_D.toFixed(3),
                        R = void 0 === h.KDJ_J ? "-" : +h.KDJ_J.toFixed(3);
                    d = [h.time, M, T, R],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "MACD":
                    var D = void 0 === h.MACD_DIF ? "-" : +h.MACD_DIF.toFixed(3),
                        E = void 0 === h.MACD_DEA ? "-" : +h.MACD_DEA.toFixed(3),
                        S = void 0 === h.MACD ? "-" : +h.MACD.toFixed(3);
                    "-" != D && "-" != E && (S = +(2 * (D - E)).toFixed(3)),
                        d = [h.time, D, E, S],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "WR":
                    var _ = void 0 === h.WR_A ? "-" : +h.WR_A.toFixed(3),
                        O = void 0 === h.WR_B ? "-" : +h.WR_B.toFixed(3);
                    d = [h.time, _, O],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "DMI":
                    var j = void 0 === h.DMI_PDI ? "-" : +h.DMI_PDI.toFixed(3),
                        B = void 0 === h.DMI_MDI ? "-" : +h.DMI_MDI.toFixed(3),
                        L = void 0 === h.DMI_ADX ? "-" : +h.DMI_ADX.toFixed(3),
                        N = void 0 === h.DMI_ADXR ? "-" : +h.DMI_ADXR.toFixed(3);
                    d = [h.time, j, B, L, N],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "BIAS":
                    var G = void 0 === h.BIAS_A ? "-" : +h.BIAS_A.toFixed(3),
                        W = void 0 === h.BIAS_B ? "-" : +h.BIAS_B.toFixed(3),
                        P = void 0 === h.BIAS_C ? "-" : +h.BIAS_C.toFixed(3);
                    d = [h.time, G, W, P],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "OBV":
                    var F = void 0 === h.OBV ? "-" : +h.OBV.toFixed(3),
                        Y = void 0 === h.OBV_MA ? "-" : +h.OBV_MA.toFixed(3);
                    d = [h.time, F, Y],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "CCI":
                    var U = void 0 === h.CCI ? "-" : +h.CCI.toFixed(3);
                    d = [h.time, U],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "ROC":
                    var z = void 0 === h.ROC ? "-" : +h.ROC.toFixed(3),
                        Z = void 0 === h.ROC_MA ? "-" : +h.ROC_MA.toFixed(3);
                    d = [h.time, z, Z],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "CR":
                    var Q = void 0 === h.CR_A ? "-" : +h.CR_A.toFixed(3),
                        J = void 0 === h.CR_B ? "-" : +h.CR_B.toFixed(3),
                        H = void 0 === h.CR_C ? "-" : +h.CR_C.toFixed(3),
                        V = void 0 === h.CR ? "-" : +h.CR.toFixed(3);
                    d = [h.time, Q, J, H, V],
                        n.push(d);
                    break;
                case "BOLL":
                    var X = void 0 === h.BOLL ? "-" : +h.BOLL.toFixed(3),
                        K = void 0 === h.BOLL_UPPER ? "-" : +h.BOLL_UPPER.toFixed(3),
                        q = void 0 === h.BOLL_LOWER ? "-" : +h.BOLL_LOWER.toFixed(3),
                        $ = void 0 === h.high ? "-" : +h.high.toFixed(3);
                    d = [h.time, X, K, q, $],
                        n.push(d)
            }
        }
        return n
    }
}
```

The last line of the funtion: '**return n**' is exactly the data I want.

I have tried **console.log(n)** in the developer's tool to print it to the console output, by overriding the original javascript with one exta line before '**return n**':

[image]

The stack trace to the function is:

```
t.exports (emcharts.min.js:formatted:936)
formatK (emcharts.min.js:formatted:31736)
D.setData (emcharts.min.js:formatted:30860)
success (emchart.js:133)
i (jquery.1.12.4.js:2)
fireWith (jquery.1.12.4.js:2)
y (jquery.1.12.4.js:4)
b.onload.b.onreadystatechange (jquery.1.12.4.js:4)
load (async)
send (jquery.1.12.4.js:4)
ajax (jquery.1.12.4.js:4)
_load (emchart.js:100)
load (emchart.js:147)
init (emchart.js:81)
bindK (emchart.js:208)
initial (emchart.js:10)
set (basestock.js:1185)
init (basestock.js:1152)
./src/modules/old_bk/old_bk.js (old_bk.js:1100)
__webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
./jssrc/bk.ts (bk.ts:11)
__webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
(anonymous) (startup:4)
(anonymous) (startup:4)
```

Comment: maybe you should check in DevTools in Chrome/Firefox if JavaScript read data from server as JSON - and then you could read it directly as JSON and calculate MACD on your own.

Comment: the big problem is that this page is not in English and hard to find any useful information. But in one menu I found link with word `API` which can means that portal may gives access directly to data - see link http://quantapi.eastmoney.com/?adid=6667. There is even link to some Python module. http://quantapi.eastmoney.com/Upload/EMQuantAPI_Python.pdf?_=637677489578965449

Comment: Yes, it's true. This external javascript accepts some original data from another URL. While the computing algorithm is way to complex to reproduce.